# How to get children records of a scoped parent in Rails 5

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I need a controller to pass along children records of parents that match a certain scope. I'd like that scope to be on the parent record.

```
class Parent < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :children

  scope :not_blue, -> { where(blue:false) }
  scope :blue,     -> { where(blue:true) }

  # Subjective, may change in the future
  scope :funny,  -> { where('funny_scale>=?',5) }

  scope :genies,     -> { blue.funny }
end

class Child < ApplicationRecord
 belongs_to :parent, required: true
end

class ChildrenController < ApplicationController
  def index
    # Yeah, this breaks horribly (and should), but you get my gist
    @children_of_genies = Parent.genies.children
  end
end
```

I know the answer is probably staring me in the face, but the right combination of google searches is eluding me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you'd like your solution to still be an `ActiveRecord::Associations::CollectionProxy` try `Children.where(parent_id: Parent.genies.ids)` which you then could turn into a scope.

`scope: children_of_genies, -> { where(parent_id: Parent.genies.ids)`

Comment: Thanks! That’s exactly what I was going for.

Answer (score 0):

Scopes return an `ActiveRecord_Relation`, to get `children` for each member of it you can use `collect`:

`@children_of_genies = Parent.genies.collect { |p| p.children }`

Comment: or `map`: `@children_of_genies = Parent.genies.map(&:children)`

Comment: @fanta +1, I always use collect when I have to create a new array and map when I'm modifying an existing one, but it's just my preference, thanks for adding it as a comment!

Comment: I like your answer — definitely the easiest way to do it, but @abax got what I needed